# Google Analytics Retention Report - How Does It Work With Custom Segments?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a rookie in google analytics and I'm trying to measure retention for a specific page.
I need to check retention of the customers who visited specific part of the website (e.g. /support) to the same part of the website (e.g. /support).

I have created a segment "people who visited /support" and I'm not sure - how does GA calculate retention for this case?

Does the report show how people return to ANY page on my website or to */support* ones?

If the answer is "any page" - is there a way to track how they return to */support* pages?